# PHP- How to get table content in the javascript confirm box?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML form, that takes the 'student Id', 'Notes' from the professor. On clicking 'Submit', it takes those values and stores it in the student_information table and displays all the content of that student.

Now I want to get confirmation from the Professor after clicking the 'submit' button. The alert box should should show him the 'Name' of the student based on the entered 'Student Id'. If he clicks 'OK', it should proceed, else it should stay in the same page.

I am having this to make sure the Professor enters the 'Notes' for the correct student. This is my HTML code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clicked('Are you sure?')
{
if((!confirm('Are you sure?'))e.preventDefault();
}
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="start.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="a.png" width="400" height="150" align="right">
<form name="frm" action="notes.php" method="POST">
<h1>STUDENT ID<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="12" MAXLENGTH="12" NAME="ID"></h1></br>
<h1>ENTER YOUR NOTES<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="80" MAXLENGTH="80" NAME="NOTES"></h1></br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you?')"></br>



<a href="home.php">Home</a>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you bring the student id, name, etc from the DB so you are sure the teacher won't make the mistake in first place?

Comment: @JulioSoares  I will be showing all the details along with notes after confirming. You are saying, first to bring all the details on the page, and then take notes from the professor. Is that what you are saying? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you should use Ajax for this. At first send request to server with id from server return student name if it exist and then show confirmation popup

Comment: I am saying...
I am assuming that if a teacher is entering notes for a student then this student already exists in table(s) with some student data.
So, instead of relying on a teacher to type the student id in a form and have to latter asking him if the id he meant is the correct id of the correct name...
why don't we bring the correct student name and id to the form and only ask the teacher for the notes?

Comment: @Sid what actually your requirement is ?

Comment: @JulioSoares thanks for your prompt reply. I will think on those lines.

Comment: @dyachenko ajax? can i put ajax code in the same php page ??

Comment: @JulioSoares I went ahead with you suggestion. First I display all the details of a student based on the given Student ID. In that page, I gave a text box to enter the notes. Upon entering the notes and submitting it, it will display all the details including the given notes.

Answer (score 0):

first see this example for calling javascript and getting the elements values:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_elements

after that I suggest you to use Ajax instead redirecting the page. send the javascript parameters to php and show the recieved results from php.
[W3C ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For the submit button, should be onclick = "return clicked('are you sure?);"?
You called the wrong function.